# memcached and miss ratio

Tags: drupal, memory, memcached

Drupal 6.15 and memcache running on RHEL 5.4 server. Memcache miss percentage is 32%. I think is is high. What can be done to improve it?

Comment: Why do you think it is high? It should depend on your traffic and cache lifetime. Essentially it should get better the more traffic you get.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly expanded form of the comment below.

A cache hit ratio will depend on a number of factors, things like

- Cache Size
- Cache timeout
- Cache clearing frequency.
- Traffic

Using memcached is most beneficial when you have a high number hits on a small amount of content. That way the cache is built quickly and then used frequently giving you a high hit ratio.

If you don't get that much traffic, cache items will be stale so will need to be re cached.

If you have traffic going to a lot of different content then the cache can either get full, or go stale before it is used again.

memcached is only something you really need to use if you are having, or anticipating scalability issues. It is not buggy, but adds another layer of application which needs to be monitored and configured.